# Action function order matters in .Net Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have encountered something odd about the actions order in a controller. Here is the first case:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/account/notification")]
public IActionResult NotificationSettings()
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/account/notification")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult NotificationSettings(NotificationSettingsModel model)
{
...
}
```

In this case, the post function isn't called from the form post action. But in the second case it's called.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/account/notification")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult NotificationSettings(NotificationSettingsModel model)
{
...
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/account/notification")]
public IActionResult NotificationSettings()
{
...
}
```

Simply, changing the order of functions in the controller changes the behaviour of the actions that is invoked in controller. Can someone explain or guide me about this?

Comment: Can you show your post code?

Comment: I think the code inside post request is irrelevant because function itself doesn't invoked from the controller.

Comment: Can you trying removing the leading `/` from route and then try @gkocyigit

Comment: It worked as you suggested! But, I am confused more. What would be the reasoning for it? The route should be given both absolute and relative.

Comment: Guide is very simple, select  the approriate meaningfull names for your actions, they should not be the same, if you don't want to guess which of them will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `/` overrides the route declared on the controller. You can refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis